# How do I turn a list of interconnected pairs of ids into a cluster of ids?

Tags: mysql, node.js, data-science

I have a table with pairs (and sometimes triples) of ids, which act as sort of links in a chain

```
+------+-----+
| from | to  |
+------+-----+
| id1  | id2 |
| id2  | id3 |
| id4  | id5 |
+------+-----+
```

I want to create a new table where all the links are clustered into chains/families:

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | familyid |
+-----+----------+
| id1 |        1 |
| id2 |        1 |
| id3 |        1 |
| id4 |        2 |
| id5 |        2 |
+-----+----------+
```

i.e. add up all chains in a link into a single family, and give it an id.
in the example above, the first 2 rows of the first table create one family, and the last row creates another family.

**Solution**

I will use node.js to query big batches of rows (a few thousands every batch), process them, and insert them into my own table with a family id.

**The issue**

The problem is I have a few tens of thousands of id pairs, and I will also need to add new ids over time after the initial creation of the families table, and i will need to add ids to existing families

Are there good algorithms for clustering pairs of data into families/clusters, keeping my issue in mind?

Comment: This would in general probably require a recursive hierarchical query, which MySQL isn't good at, followed by some more olympics to get family numbers assigned.  Possible, but a bit of work.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I have done something very similar in the past few months, but when I worked on it, I did it without a plan, and just started working with big json arrays, merging, mapping, reducing, and doing a whole bunch of said "olympics" and ended up with a solution. only now I have no idea how to backtrack and do it again. this is why i'm here now, trying to find out if there is something more "official" out there that can help me do it without spreadsheet diving.

Comment: OK...is there a fixed depth to a family tree?  If not, then you would almost certainly need dynamic SQL for this; that's above my pay grade.

Comment: I'm not planning on a single sql query which will do this for me, I'm thinking of querying batches of data from the first table, doing some node.js processing, and inserting it into the new table, possibly with multiple statements.

Comment: No, I would probably try to handle this entirely in the database, unless there is a pressing reason to do otherwise.  How deep is the hierarchy?

Comment: One good reason is that the new table will be created in a totally different mysql host than the source table. my source table is in a read-only database for me.

Comment: As for hierarchy, it's just links in a chain, it can be up to even 20 ids in a single family, and more ids might be added weeks from now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's an answer as more some ideas...
I created two tables similar to the ones you have, the first one I populated with the same data as you have.

```
Table Base, fromID, toID
Table chain, fromID, chainID (numeric, null allowed)
```

I then inserted all unique values from Base into chain with a null value for chainID.  The idea being these are the rows as yet unprocessed.

It was then a case of repeatedly running a couple of statements...

```
update chain c 
  set chainID = n 
  where chainid is null and exists ( select 1 from base b where b.fromID = c.fromID )
  order by fromID 
  limit 1
```

This would allocate the next chain ID to the first row without one (n needs to be generated from somewhere and incremented each time you run this)

Then the one that relates all of the records...

```
update chain c 
    join base b on b.toID = c.fromID
    join chain c1 on b.fromID = c1.fromID
    set c.chainID = c1.chainID 
    where c.chainID is null and c1.chainID is not null
```

This is run repeatedly until it affects 0 rows (i.e. it's nothing more to do).
Then run the first update to create the next chain etc.  Again if you run the first update till it affects 0 rows, this shows that they are all linked.

Would be interested if you want to try this and see if it stands up with more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like clustering over graph dataset where 'familyid' is the cluster center number.

[Here is a question I think is relevant.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130840/efficient-graph-clustering-algorithm)

[Here is the algorithm description.](https://micans.org/mcl/) You will need to implement under the conditions you described.