# How to cluster pairs of IDs in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-analysis

I have a column that shows distinct pairs of IDs:

```
|column1|column2|
|123|456|
|123|678|
|678|315|
|333|777|
```

And I am trying to make clusters of these IDs, based on an overlap between of of the IDs, by perhaps adding a family ID:

```
|column1|column2|column3
|123|456|1|
|123|678|1|
|678|315|1|
|333|777|2|
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

I've looked into the following question which was very useful for me in describing this case:
[see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758747/how-do-i-turn-a-list-of-interconnected-pairs-of-ids-into-a-cluster-of-ids)

Now I'm thinking about ways to make this fixable in Pyspark. Any suggestions here?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your linked question said, you'll need some graph clustering algorithm. Fortunately, there is a [graphframes](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/index.html) package which does everything for you. To use graphframes on pyspark-shell, you can simply do

```
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12
```

Here's an example of how to do it for your problem:

```
df.show()
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|    123|    456|
|    123|    678|
|    678|    315|
|    333|    777|
+-------+-------+

from graphframes import GraphFrame
vertices = df.select('column1').union(df.select('column2')).distinct().toDF('id')
edges = df.toDF('src', 'dst')
g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)

sc.setCheckpointDir('/tmp')
cc = g.connectedComponents().cache()

results = df.join(cc, df.column1 == cc.id).drop('id')
results.show()
+-------+-------+---------+
|column1|column2|component|
+-------+-------+---------+
|    333|    777|      333|
|    678|    315|      123|
|    123|    678|      123|
|    123|    456|      123|
+-------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the code gets stuck at g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges). Not sure what's the reason behind this..? Perhaps the dataframe is too large as it contains hundreds of thousands of pairs..

Comment: Oh, then remove `.repartition(1)`. That's only here because it's a tiny example.

Comment: hmmm unfortunately that doesn't solve this either as still the same error is thrown: "ClassNotFoundException: org.graphframes.GraphFramePythonAPI" Guess, there's still something wrong in the code, will have a deeper look at GraphFrames Overview later today

Comment: @Antonius oh yes, I forgot to mention that you need to download the graphframes jar to your machine as well, and put it to `$SPARK_HOME/jars`

Comment: @Antonius you can download it [here](http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/graphframes/graphframes/0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12/graphframes-0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12.jar)

Comment: thanks I will look into it tomorrow and share the outcome in this section!

Comment: There's some issues with my spark application that makes it difficult for me to use these graphframes. Therefore, I will have to park this for now... Either way I did make some improvements as I'm able to run the code, albeit extremely slow, which I will figure out a a later point. Your help was useful, so I considered this as to be answered.